# WPF listview change observable collection properties with button inside ListView Item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection

I am using WPF list view bound in XAML to to Observable collection. Below is my list view Item Template which generates view like

[ListView Item looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZzXn.png)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageOverlayAlbumDataTemplate">
  <Grid>
      <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" Background="White" Height="50" Width="240" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition  />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition  />
                                    <RowDefinition  />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Border Name="ActionStatusIndicator" Height="50" Width="7" Margin="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <Border.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=statusid}" Value="3">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="SteelBlue"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=statusid}" Value="4">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=statusid}" Value="5">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=statusid}" Value="6">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Border.Style>

                            </Border>
                            <!--</StackPanel>-->
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding subject}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="230" Height="20" FontSize="13"
                                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left"
                                            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=displayname}" FontSize="10" Margin="10,3,0,0" Width="110" Height="20" 
                                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left"
                                           Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

                                <Image x:Name="sideButton" Source="/Icons/action.png" Width="20" Height="20"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                                    <Image.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                </DataTrigger>

                                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=StatusID}" Value="3" />

                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                </MultiDataTrigger>

                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Image.Style>
                                </Image>

                            </Grid>

                    </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

              </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I want to change 'StatusId' to some other number when user clicks on image (tick) which appear on mouse hover.

StatusID is present in ActionView Class as int and above list is bound to

Comment: above list is bound to ObservableCollection<ActionView>.
I am not able to understand how i can change StatusId property of Item where user click on mouse hover image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Image element to a Button that you re-template to appear as the image:

```
   <Button Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
Command={Binding Path=ChangeStatusCommand}>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image x:Name="sideButton" Source="/Icons/action.png"    >
...
```

And you maybe wanna move the triggers out to the template or button...

And you need to create a ICommand (or something that implements it) in the same object that you have the StatusID (or you can create it somewhere else too, but that on that place you need to have a referense to the object that have the StatusID)
Now you can write C#-code to change the StatusID when pushing the image.
You also need to make sure that the StatusID property uses the INotifyPropertyChange event to alert the XAML to be updated.

Comment: Thanks zwi...that was exactly i was looking for.
It is working fine now and my Observable collection is holding updated values.
Could you also share some thoughts on how i can write this observable collection back to DB, so that next time when view loads again, it will have updated data.

Comment: thanks, just realize I was using the wrong nick/display name here :-) (change now)